# Jersey 2.0: Equivalent to EntityHolder<T>

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

What is the equivalent to `EntityHolder<T>` available in Jersey 1.x to represent an optional payload on server-side. I have tried `Enity<T>` and `GenericEntity<T>` both do not work. I cannot find any hint in the documentation.

Is it allowed to call `SyncInvoker#post(null)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hasEntity` and `readEntity` methods of `ContainerRequest` to support empty bodies.

```
public void post(@Context ContainerRequest request){
  MyEntity entity = null;
  if(request.hasEntity()){
    entity = request.readEntity(MyEntity.class);
  }
  //use the optional entity.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Fortunately, I came to the same solution, but its good to know that this is the "offical" approach.